# TypeError: lists.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am working on a project in react, which consists of being able to drag a list from one side to another, like the Trello task application, and I am encountering this error: TypeError: Cannot read the 'cards' owned by undefined. At the moment of releasing the list I get that error. Thanks in advance with any help!

```js
const ListContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

class App extends Component {
//When we Dragg and drop the lists
  onDragEnd = result => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId, type } = result;
    console.log("hi from func", type)
    if(!destination) {
      return;
    }

    this.props.dispatch(
      sort(
        source.droppableId,
        destination.droppableId,
        source.index,
        destination.index,
        draggableId,
        type
      )
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { lists } = this.props;

    return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        <Navbar />
        <Droppable droppableId="all-lists" direction="horizontal" type="list">
          {provided => (
            <ListContainer
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {lists.map((list, index) => (
                <TrelloList
                  listID={list.id}
                  key={list.id}
                  title={list.title}
                  cards={list.cards}
                  index={index}
                />
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            <TrelloButton list/>
          </ListContainer>
          )}
        </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
    )
  };
};

//Connect with react-redux
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  lists: state.lists
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (App);
```

Comment: check what's in your Redux store - it seems at least one element of the array in the `lists` key is `undefined`

Comment: OMG! I made a mistake with the title of the question, sorry and thanks for your answer Robin. I'll ask the question again. the error is the following: TypeError: lists.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: lists.map is not a function` is an error that usually comes up when you try to map over an object instead of an array as you should. Check what `lists` actually is to make sure it's an array that's formatted correctly.

Comment: Hello, Sean I have it solved ¡thank you! Turns out it had too many returns and didn't allow list rendering. and :-/ I wrote the wrong list in reducers, I put lists instead of list.